# recursive dictionary creation python

Tags: python, dictionary

is there any way to dynamically create missing keys if i want to want to set a variable in a subdictionary.

essentially I want to create any missing keys and set my value.

```
self.portdict[switchname][str(neighbor['name'])]['local']['ports'] = []
```

currently i'm doing it but its messy:

```
if not switchname in self.portdict:
    self.portdict[switchname] = {}
if not str(neighbor['name']) in self.portdict[switchname]:
    self.portdict[switchname][str(neighbor['name'])] = {}
if not 'local' in self.portdict[switchname][str(neighbor['name'])]:
    self.portdict[switchname][str(neighbor['name'])]['local'] = {}
if not 'ports' in self.portdict[switchname][str(neighbor['name'])]['local']:
    self.portdict[switchname][str(neighbor['name'])]['local']['ports'] = []
```

Is there any way to do this in one or two lines instead?

Answer (score 3):

This is easier to do without recursion:

```
def set_by_path(dct, path, value):
    ipath = iter(path)
    p_last = next(ipath)
    try:
        while True:
            p_next = next(ipath)
            dct = dct.setdefault(p_last, {})
            p_last = p_next
    except StopIteration:
        dct[p_last] = value
```

And a test case:

```
d = {}
set_by_path(d, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], 'qux')
print d  # {'foo': {'bar': {'baz': 'qux'}}}
```

If you want to have it so you don't need a function, you can use the following defaultdict factory which allows you to nest things arbitrarily deeply:

```
from collections import defaultdict

defaultdict_factory = lambda : defaultdict(defaultdict_factory)

d = defaultdict_factory()
d['foo']['bar']['baz'] = 'qux'
print d
```

Comment: The recursive `defaultdict` factory is an interesting idea! I hadn't thought of doing that.

Comment: That fails when the OP wants a `list` at the last depth.

Comment: @o11c -- Not really.  It just means that OP needs to set it explicitly.  `d['foo']['bar']['baz'] = []` or `d['foo']['bar'] = defaultdict(list)` which OP has to do for any of the other answers as well...

Comment: @mgilson - "_which OP has to do for any of the other answers as well..._" I don't think you read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26223651/1427124). The OP would need to specify that he wants a `list` at the last level, but it's done automatically rather than having to explicitly set it each time. I think that makes a big difference in usability (which is why I wrote it that way for use in my own code).

Answer (score 1):

Use `collections.defaultdict`

```
self.portdict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: []))))
```

Comment: Its better to put `defaultdict(list)` at the end

Comment: @matsjoyce I figured it's more obvious this say, since most people don't think of `list` as a callable

Comment: I'd argue that those who do not think of `list` as callable do not know much about `lambda`s. But, what ever you think helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar problem in the past. I found that `defaultdict` was the right answer for me—but writing the super long definitions (like the one in @o11c's answer or @Apero's answer) was no good. Here's what I came up with instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import partial

def NestedDefaultDict(levels, baseFn):
    def NDD(lvl):
        return partial(defaultdict, NDD(lvl-1)) if lvl > 0 else baseFn
    return defaultdict(NDD(levels-1))
```

This creates a dictionary with `levels` of nested dictionaries. So if you have `levels`=3, then you need 3 keys to access the bottom-level value. The second argument is a function which is used to create the bottom-level values. Something like `list` or `lambda: 0` or even `dict` would work well.

Here's an example of using the "automatic" keys with 4 `levels`, and `list` as the default function:

```
>>> x = NestedDefaultDict(4, list)
>>> x[1][2][3][4].append('hello')
>>> x
defaultdict(<functools.partial object at 0x10b5c22b8>, {1: defaultdict(<functools.partial object at 0x10b5c2260>, {2: defaultdict(<functools.partial object at 0x10b5c2208>, {3: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {4: ['hello']})})})})
```

I think that's basically what you'd want for the case in your question. Your 4 "levels" are *switch-name, neighbor-name, local, & ports*—and it looks like you want a `list` at the bottom-level to store your ports.

Another example using 2 `levels` and `lambda: 0` as the default:

```
>>> y = NestedDefaultDict(2, lambda: 0)
>>> y['foo']['bar'] += 7
>>> y['foo']['baz'] += 10
>>> y['foo']['bar'] += 1
>>> y
defaultdict(<functools.partial object at 0x1021f1310>, {'foo': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x1021f3938>, {'baz': 10, 'bar': 8})})
```

Comment: Cool answer, though IMO the right thing would actually be to introduce additional classes for the middle levels, so that each class just contains one-deep `defaultdict`s

Comment: @o11c - That's an interesting opinion. I would think that adding additional classes is just pointless complexity since you don't actually _use_ the classes for anything but to wrap a `defaultdict`. On the other hand, I think it would be beneficial to _completely_ replace some levels of `defaultdict`s with class instances. For example, `local` and `ports` seem more like class field names than dynamic dictionary entries, so replacing those to levels with classes that have `local` and `ports` fields might be better. Maybe that's what you meant.

Comment: Particularly I was thinking that `portdict[switchname]` should obviously return a `Switch`, and `switch[neighborname]` should return a `Neighbor`

Answer (score 0):

Have a close look to collections.defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
foo = defaultdict(dict)
foo['bar'] = defaultdict(dict)
foo['bar']['baz'] = defaultdict(dict)
foo['bar']['baz']['aaa'] = 1
foo['bor'] = 0
foo['bir'] = defaultdict(list)
foo['bir']['biz'].append(1)
foo['bir']['biz'].append(2)

print foo
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'bir': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'biz': [1, 2]}), 'bor': 0, 'bar': defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'baz': defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'aaa': 1})})})
```

Comment: I saw some other answer mentionning defaultdict after I posted this one.
OP, you decide if this helps understanding defaultdict, otherwise I'll delete it